# How to configure NetPlan as a wired 802.1X Authenticator?

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan, hostapd

I would like configure a wired Ethernet port to support 802.1X authentication.

`hostapd` supports 802.1X authentication. How do I use `hostapd` with NetPlan?

NetPlan supports the `auth` section for interfaces including `key-management: 802.1x`, however these settings appear to be for configuring the (WPA) Supplicant side of 802.1X (ie accessing a protected interface).

I would like to create the protected interface.

The current `hostapd` installation installs ifupdown support. Of course this is not useful for NetPlan.

The additional twist is that we are using `renderer: NetworkManager` on a server (due to configuring a cellular (gsm) modem).

- Ubuntu 18.04
- NetPlan
- NetworkManager
- 802.1X protected interface
- hostapd

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, I never understood why one wants to configure the network via metplan, when both supported renderers (systemd-networkd and NetworkManager) have their documented (and sensible?) ways to allow users to configure them. Meaning, why would you write a netplan yaml, when you could use nmcli and keyfiles in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections directly?

So my answer would be: just configure the profile in NetworkManager. NetworkManager supports 802.1x port authentication. For example use `nmcli`. Create a profile of type `ethernet` and add `802-1x` settings. See `man nm-settings`.

Comment: Thank you @thaller. The settings from NetworkManager look similar to the built-in settings for NetPlan. I think these settings are for authenticating to an 802.1X interface on Ethernet. Rather, I'm looking for the opposite. I want the Ethernet interface to be the Authenticator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X). I believe these settings are for being a supplicant.  Please correct me if these settings can setup an Authenticator.